# Adding CakePHP folder to existing domain

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

Right now some of our domains which are drupal sites, have a cakephp app associated with them, like it is a directory within that domains directory, but the cakephp app is outside of that domains directory. www.domain.com/thecakephpapp is how it looks and what I would type to get to the cakephp part. But in /var/www the two are seperate like:

drwxr-xr-x 14 user www-data   4096 2011-06-03 15:25 domain.com
drwxr-xr-x 10 user www-data   4096 2012-04-11 16:08 cakephpapp

I have no idea where to associate them together though. So that when I type in www.domain.com/cakephpapp it points to the location of cakephpapp. I've looked at the ones setup before me but haven't been able to make heads or tales of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get this right "var/wwwdomain.com" is the folder that is used as webroot by your domain.com website. If the cakeapp is in /var/www/cakeapp the most easy solution would be to symlink it.

```
ln -s /var/www/cakeapp/webroot /var/www/wwwdomain.com/cakeapp
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out you can do something similar with an Alias in apache. And it would look something like this in your apache configuration file.

```
Alias /cakeapp /web/cakeapp/webroot
```